# New collection of the joined collections with $lookup

Tags: mongodb

I'm joining 2 collections with $lookup in MongoDB. I tried using $out to put the result in a new collection but it shows me an error

```
db.user.aggregate([{$out:{ $lookup:{ from: "work", localField: "adr", foreignField: "adr", as: "wrokdoc" } }} ]);
```

Comment: Have you tried using $out ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: It gives me an error 
$out stage requires a string argument, but found object

Comment: Add your query into the question & maybe someone can help